# createProgram does not respect compilerOptions.paths?

Tags: typescript

Here is a test case: https://github.com/alekbarszczewski/test-compiler-options. It seems that ts `createProgram(...)` does not respect compilerOptions.paths. Program output is:

```
[ '.../test-compiler-options/src/dep1.ts',
  '.../test-compiler-options/src/main.ts' ]
```

while it should be:

```
[ '.../test-compiler-options/src/dep1.ts',
  '.../test-compiler-options/src/dep2.ts',
  '.../test-compiler-options/src/main.ts' ]
```

Any idea how I can make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `typescript` docs, you need to specify `baseUrl` when using `paths`.

```
const program = ts.createProgram(
  [join(__dirname, 'main.ts')],
  {
    baseUrl: '.', // <- add this
    paths: {
      '@/*': ['src/*'],
    },
  },
);
```

If that does not work, use a relative path (as a workaround) to import the module from main.ts, and file  a bug at `typescript`.